# jquery mobile swipe event not captured on page with embedded swf

Tags: jquery, mobile, flash, swipe

I have a page on which I have an embedded swf file almost full page... when swipe occurs on top of embedded swf, the swipe event is not firing... if I swipe in the very bottom or top where the swf object does not extend to, the event is fired and I can capture it... anybody know a workaround for swiping on top of swf objects?

Comment: looks like problem with event bubbling from flash see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301680/event-not-bubbling-in-some-browsers-when-clicked-on-flash

Comment: I'd also suggest reporting this to JQM issue tracker

Comment: sabithpocker's link to the post fixed my issue... thanks much! You rock!

Comment: UPDATE: Although sabithpocker's referenced post fixed my issue, it was just the wmode parameter that I needed to add to my code to capture the swipe event... the span with a transparent gif is not needed... the wmode parameter allows for the dom to capture the swipe event...