# Keydown event no longer triggered after click

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I have a website were I'd like to react upon arrow key events. I added a `keydown` listener, which works as long as I don't click in the site. After clicking, the `keydown` no longer gets triggered.

Since the behavior is the same for *Chrome* and *Firefox* I suspect I am missing something.

Following the source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body, embed 
            {
                position: absolute;
                width:  100%;
                height: 100%;
                margin:  0px;
                padding: 0px;
                border:  0px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>    
            var keyHandler = function(event) {
                alert( "EV" + event );
            };
            window.addEventListener( 'keydown', keyHandler, true );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <embed src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6b/Bitmap_VS_SVG.svg"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Could someone point out, what I am missing?

Comment: have you tried document.addEventListener? (untested)

Comment: `document.addEventListener` has the exact same behavior.

Comment: Do you have jquery? or willing to use it? There is an accepted solution using this

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're using an `embed` element for the entire viewport. Embed elements are for embedding multimedia into your site. Once the focus is moved to that element (by clicking), it hijacks your events.

You can see this in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/p6rXP/ Click in the results window but not on the image and press a key. Then click on the image and press a key. Then click off the image and press a key.

If you use an `img` element instead of an `embed` the problem is resolved: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/p6rXP/1/

Comment: Can I then still add eventHandlers to the elements in the svg?

Answer (score 1):

Brent's answer gave you the rationale for this and the clean solution, I will give you the crude workaround in case you can't stop using an `embed` tag.

That is to place an invisible span or div element above your embed viewport, that way when people click over the embed content they will be really clicking on your invisible element so the focus is not transfered to the embededd element and so your `window.keydown` handler will be fired.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/9614949/352672 for an example code for this workaround.

Comment: Since I want to add event handlers for clicking in the SVG, this isn't really an option either :(

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was loading the external SVG into the document body. The whole problem goes away then (while others surface).
With *jquery* this would look like so:

```
<body>
    <script>
        $(document.body).load("mygreat.svg");
    </script>
</body>
```