# How to set a key to change style of a node?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, key, greasemonkey

I'm doing an userscript of Greasemonkey and I want set a key to change style `display:""` of `none` to `block` and vice versa of a node by press a key ("Home" in this case).

```
var bluebar = document.getElementById('pagelet_bluebar');
bluebar.style.display = "none";
document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 36) {
        showhideui();
    }
}, false);
function showhideui() {
    if (bluebar.style.display = "none") {
        bluebar.style.display = "block";
    } else if (bluebar.style.display = "block") {
        bluebar.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

The solution was add `==` instead `=` in the conditions:

```
if (bluebar.style.display == "none")
else if (bluebar.style.display == "block")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  `==` or `===` instead of single `=` sign in your comparison.
Check this link about [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

```
 var bluebar = document.getElementById('pagelet_bluebar');
   document.addEventListener("keydown", function (e) {
       if (e.keyCode === 36) { //press "Home" key change to block/none
           showhideui();
       }
   }, false);
   function showhideui() {
       if (bluebar.style.display == "none") { //if is none
           bluebar.style.display = "block" ; //change to block
       } else if (bluebar.style.display == "block" || bluebar.style.display == "") { //if is block
           bluebar.style.display = "none"; //change to none
       }
   }
```

Ps: If there is only those two possibilities, you could even use a more synthetic way  :

```
(bluebar.style.display == "block" || bluebar.style.display == "") ? bluebar.style.display = "none" : bluebar.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: I don't get errors in console, I use the default console of Firefox... Is better the console of extension Firebug?

Comment: I do prefer firebug but it's all personal.

Comment: Ok, my bad... The single problem was `=` instead `==` in the condition ever. Never works the script because when I have focus on a embed plugin like Unity Web Player or Flash Player, the key shortcuts or binds don't work lol... Now my problem is, There is some way to can use key shortcuts/binds although I have focus on a plugin? :P

Comment: Ok, You may want to start a new question about that but you could watch to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301680/event-not-bubbling-in-some-browsers-when-clicked-on-flash